# coffeescript dictionary set default

Tags: python, dictionary, coffeescript

In Python if you have a dictionary that consists of lists like

```
   mydict = {'foo': [], 'bar':[3, 4]}
```

and if you want to add something into that lists you can do

```
   mydict.setdefault('baz', []).append(5)
```

not to write

```
key, list_element = 'baz', 5
if key in mydict:
    mydict[key].append(list_element)
else:
    mydict[key] = [list_element]
```

is there an equivalent for this in Coffeescript?

Comment: In Python, what you really want is probably a `collections.defaultdict(list)`. Then appending a value is `mylist['baz'].append(5)`. (Also, `mylist` is a misleading name for a dict.)

Comment: Using setdefault for the Python code instead of `collections.defaultdict` is perfectly fine, I actually prefer it because you are still using a regular dictionary so you will get KeyErrors when referencing non-existing elements instead of an empty list (or whatever else the defaultdict is creating).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option:

```
(mydict.baz or (mydict.baz = [])).push(5)
```

In this case the CoffeeScript is extremely similar to the JavaScript it generates:

```
(mydict.baz || (mydict.baz = [])).push(5);
```

Comment: There's also `(mydict.baz ||= [ ]).push(6)` if you don't want to mention `baz` twice.

Answer (score 8):

i recommend against using `||`/ `or` to test for membership—it's basically a clever trick that will silently fail against falsy values. i prefer to write

```
( mydict[ name ]?= [] ).push value
```

which i find clearer; it assumes that in case `mydict` does not have an entry for `name` or
that value is `null` or `undefined`, then an empty list should be put there at this point.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind employing `underscore.js`.

http://underscorejs.org/#defaults

```
var iceCream = {flavor : "chocolate"};
_.defaults(iceCream, {flavor : "vanilla", sprinkles : "lots"});
=> {flavor : "chocolate", sprinkles : "lots"}
```